# Stop Readchars/readbytes after reading a 00 byte

Tags: c#, char, byte

is there a way to stop `BinaRyreader.readchars()`/`BinaryReader.readbytes()` when encountering a 00 byte ?? thank you.

sample:

```
for (int i = 0x88; i <= num_pointers; i += 0x50)
            {
                br.BaseStream.Position = i;
                listView1.Items.Add(br.ReadBytes(21).ToString());
            }
```

Comment: nothing actually, i kept searching in google, no answers, or either i'm asking the wrong question :s, i tried an if, but it gives me an error.

Comment: Well, what is your code for reading atm? I guess you use some sort of loop? If you post some of the code I might be able to help you.

Comment: done sir, the 21 chars are just temp till i know how to make it read and stop at 00 encounter :) thank you.

Comment: I'd consider reading in one Byte at a time. Then you can use a loop to check if the previously read in value was 0x00, in which case exit your loop.

Comment: Thank you, that was long but it worked :D, could you please post it as a solution ? so i can end the question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use ReadByte instead of ReadBytes.

Then add an inner loop, so that instead of reading in chunks, you read just one byte at a time. Use a while loop so that you keep reading until the value you just read is 0x0.